# Needed small explanation of the notation in this paper

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation

There is [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.50.6374) paper: http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/43192/1/p6374_1.pdf

In equation (36) of this, the second line ($\omega^{+ij} =\dots$), there is a term $\partial_{[i}\bar\lambda\delta_{j\,]k}$ that I didn't understand. What does this notation mean?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_tensor#Notation

Comment: As Christoph said, this is antisymmetric notation, but be cautious. Sometimes people don't use $n!$ multiplication in front of it. So, up to $n!$ or $1/n!$, $A_{[i}B_{j]}=A_iB_j-A_jB_i$

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79157/2451

Comment: Thank you all for your fast reply. @MEDVIS I see, but I have also one thing to add, what about the small $k$ at the right side of the bracket? What does it mean here? And also there is a $\delta$ beside the $\lambda$ so if according to your notation I say let $\lambda$ be your $B$ I still don't know what is the $\delta$ and $k$. Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Fluctuations: $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker-delta (a rank-2 tensor), but you only anti-symmetrize over one of its indices, leaving $k$ fixed

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the reply, so I would get if I unwrapped this equal to: $\partial_i \lambda \delta_{jk} - \partial_j \lambda \delta_{ik}$? Right?

Comment: @Fluctuations: Right (modulo a factor of $1/2$ depending on the chosen convention)

Comment: @Christoph You're welcome. By the way, if you need to anti-symmetrize over $i$ and $k$, the notation will be $\partial_{[i}\lambda \delta_{|j|k]}$.